# No versions could be resolved for groupid.artifactid

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I'm having an error while listing the Mavaen Repository Artifacts in my Jenkins server configuration. Error is given below.

```
No versions could be resolved for groupid.artifactid rtis.rtis_2.11
```

[image: Error Message]
But my Nexus server contains the available **rtis** versions correctly. My point is how I can retrieve those versions available in Nexus server to my Jenkins server?

Available versions in Nexus server
[image: Versions available in Nexus server]

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Thank You.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As I figured out, automatically upadating **mavan-metadata.xml** file is the solution. In order to update the file, create a task sheduler for **rebuild metadata** with a **cron** job. 
Go to Administration -> Scheduled Tasks in Nexus Repo. For more info, please refer to the image given below.
[image: Cron job]

Answer (score 0):

Jenkins is not finding nexus repository to resolve the artifact.

Verify these settings are correct in Maven POM:

```
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>project</id>
      <url>https://yourreposerver/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </repository>
  </repositories>

  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>project</id>
      <url>https://yourreposerver/nexus/content/groups/public/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
```

Also, Jenkins plugin [help](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Repository+Connector+Plugin) page, will give you more information on what kind of settings you might be missing while setting up your job.

Comment: Already checked those settings everything is correct, Just tried with another artifact_id & group_i, it was working.

Comment: But still "rtis" group_id & artifact_id are not resolving

Comment: can please check- display,  the actual pom of this rtis library?

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the type in the dependency to be downloaded. By default in Maven it is 'jar'. However in your case it it 'tgz' so you have to specify that provided that is possible in the Jenkins user interface. I can not see that option but it should be there.

The other potential problem is that is was flagged as not found in the local repository Jenkins is using. Then you would have to either delete the metadata or force an update of it. On the Maven commandline this would be done with -U however in your UI I am not sure.

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Manfred, when I try to manually update **maven-metadata.xml**  the list is updated and works fine. But it's not updating automatically when there's a change.