# For hosted repos: No versions could be resolved for groupid.artifactid

Tags: maven, jenkins, nexus

I have a hosted nexus repo. Am using repository connector to download the artifact from nexus. Here I face "No versions could be resolved for groupid.artifactid" in maven repository artifact step.

I did followed [No versions could be resolved for groupid.artifactid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34541331/no-versions-could-be-resolved-for-groupid-artifactid) and updated maven-metadata still I face the same issue.

My pom file [pom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2WFFV.png)

Exception in jenkins [No versions resolved from nexus- in jenkins](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UjcBO.png)

Note: This is an ant built project. For the sake of artifact resolver I have created the pom. In order to avoid the pom file missing warnings.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.
Thanks In Advance

Comment: Show your pom file show the full error output etc. otherwise it's hard to say what's going wrong...

Comment: So my problem is ant build project. And trying to download using mvn repository connector plugin. Version I created for the artifact is build number but its pom version is hard coded to 0.1. Is there a ant plugin to download artifacts from nexus and list its versions without the need for pom??

Comment: If that a Maven problem or an Ant problem? And I repeat show your full project and the pom's you are using...

Comment: @khmarbaise its a maven problem I believe. Repository connector plugin reads version info from pom's in the given repo and retrieves the version list of artifacts. Since mine is a ant build project and I created a pom file.

Comment: A first look on the pom files shows that you didn't understand the conventions...cause you are configuring to exclude `*.java` from `src/main/resources` where never should be java source files be located..on the other hand your configuration tries to exclude java files from `src/main/java` which does not really makes sense cause java files should be located in `src/main/java` and resources files in `src/main/resources`. Furthermore I have to admit that I really don't understand what you like to achieve with this setup? Why not using Maven directly instead via Ant ? What is the purpose?

Comment: Its because of the requirement. Am trying continuous integration for the current ant build project set up. My counterparts doesn't  like to change it to mvn way of doing things [Like updating poms after every change]. While working on CI with jenkins I was carried out with lot of mvn plugins and the need for pom files. Hence I thought of adding a pom. Now I understood pom with right version update is required.

Comment: I have used nexus artifact uploader plugin for pushing the artifact to nexus. As mentioned  its without pom, in that case when I resolve artifacts using repository connector I get "class org.apache.maven.wagon.ResourceDoesNotExistException: Unable to locate resource in repository
Downloading: http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/repo/com/kohler/attributes/25-5fae77e8/attributes-25-5fae77e8.pom in jenkins job console.

Comment: POM's can be updated automatically via versions-maven-plugin and if you use a CI solution no problem..

Comment: Hence am trying with mvn deploy plugin:: "mvn deploy:deploy-file -Dversion=12-Durl=http://localhost:8081/nexus/content/repositories/Database_Library -DgroupId=com-Dfile=../.jenkins/workspace/attributeskeywordimporter-push/dist/Attributes.jar-Drepositoryid=Database_Library -Dpackaging=jar -DgeneratePom=true -DartifactId=attributes" Now I get Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:2.7:deploy-file (default-cli) on project standalone-pom: Failed to deploy artifacts:  Return code is: 401, ReasonPhrase: Unauthorized. -> I have included the server details in settings.xml.

Comment: By this way I thought mvn generates a pom.xml and I need not provide one. But it always returns 401. I used the same credentials to upload it through nexus artifacts uploader. It works.

Comment: @khmarbaise thanks. I used the mvn versions:set -DnewVersion={buildnumber} cmd. And able to update poms and retrieve bck the version list using repository connector. Still this would have been good if there is no need to create a pom and just create and update it with versions on the run while executing jobs. I will try for that with maven deploy file.

Answer (score 0):

its the way I use repository connector. Repository connector plugin reads version info from pom files in the given repo and retrieves the version- list of artifacts. Since mine is a ant build project, I created a pom file with hard coded version[0.1] and artifact version[configured as build number]. Hence pom version dint match with artifact and no versions could be resolved.

If I deploy the artifact with 0.1 as version, same like pom version. Then the version list is retrieved as expected by repository connector.